# Is it possible to determine the source of an incoming request?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is it possible to know the hostname of the source of an incoming request to a cloud firestore document? I would like to write a database rule of the form `allow write: if request.resource.data.source_host_name == some_predefined_value`. This is a web application so I'm trying to find a good way to limit who gets to write to my database without using traditional auth methods.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a `hostname`?  Each user will have an IP address, but not a hostname.  What limits do you want to achieve, that you can't do with Firebase Authentication?

Comment: @JasonBerryman - Thanks for the question. Because of the specifics of this particular application, Firebase Authentication can't be used. It may be possible to use anonymous authentication but I don't think that will provide sufficient security. I'm looking for a way to add a condition that the user is coming from a known site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That sort of rule is not possible with Cloud Firestore.  It also wouldn't be very secure, as it's possible to [spoof source IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing).

If you want to limit who can access your database, the only supported mechanism is through security rules and Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Answer (score 5):

Here's my solution to logging a client's IP address when interacting with Firestore. I agree with Doug that this won't guard against IP spoofing. Nonetheless, it's helpful for my purposes.

The trick is to create intermediary API endpoints using Cloud Functions, which then interact with Firestore. Here's an example Google Cloud function.

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.yourEndpoint = functions.https.onRequest(req, (res) => {
  // Get the IP address from the headers in the request object
  const ipAddress = getIPAddress(req);

  // Do whatever you need in your firestore DB with ipAddress
  admin.firestore().collection('ipAddresses').add({address: ipAddress})
    .then((writeResult) => {
      return res.status(200).send();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return res.status(500).send();
    });
});

// Helper function to extract the IP address from request headers
function getIPAddress(req) {
  return (
    req.headers["fastly-client-ip"] ||
    req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] ||
    req.headers["No IP, probably because we are in development mode"]
  );
}
```

Note: you won't get an IP address in development mode, because the Firebase emulators don't create the proper headers.

Comment: hi, how do you change the firestore client's endpoint to go to the cloud function? thx