# Firebase JavaScript SDK - Retrieve Users IP Address

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Assuming my browser script automatically signs any user in anonymously, is it possible to collect the users public IP address? I found the `firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata` property but it only includes `LastSignInTime` and `creationTime`. Is the users public IP address available via the Firebase authentication (or any part of the Firebase JavaScript API) system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Authentication does not expose IP address as part of the user record, nor is it exposed anywhere in the client side SDKs.  You will need a backend to record that for yourself.

Comment: any idea of the rationale behind this? Firebase is my backend/server (aka server-less convenience).

Comment: No. You can always file a feature request to explain your use case.  But end user IP addresses (or at least the IP address that one backend perceives the user to be using) can change frequently for any number of reasons, so knowing it at one moment in time won't be very helpful.

Comment: A single user can be signed in from multiple devices, which could translate to multiple different IP addresses. An IP address can also be easily spoofed by malicious users.

Comment: Here's how I dealt with getting the client's IP address: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61807036/1311267