# A way to get the IP address of a user in Firebase Authentication?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Does Firebase log the IP address that the user last signed in from?

The reason that I need it is that I want to try to broadly segment my users by location, and IP address will usually help with this.

But I'm not sure if the data exists in Firebase or is query-able.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Firebase Authentication does not make the IP address of the user available. See [Firebase JavaScript SDK - Retrieve Users IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926896/firebase-javascript-sdk-retrieve-users-ip-address)

But what you describe sounds like a use-case better suited to Firebase Analytics/Google Analytics for Firebase, which **does** expose the user's location (based on a lookup from their IP address).